# Getting TypeError: this.props.users is undefined when changing 'this.state' to 'this.props.users' in simple React tutorial

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'm following a simple React tutorial bring data through from an object. It works fine when I use state to bring through the data but when I switch this to "this.props.users;" I get the error this.props.users is undefined. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong. See code below. Thank you.

users.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import UserItem from './userItem'

class users extends Component {

    state = {
        users: [
            {
                id: '1',
                login: 'dannyboy11',
                name: 'Dan'
            },
            {
                id: '2',
                login: 'katie123',
                name: 'Kate'
            },
            {
                id: '3',
                login: 'putty89123',
                name: 'Putty'
            },
        ]
    }
    
    render() {
        
        return (
            <div>
                
                {this.state.users.map(users => (
                    <UserItem users={users}  />
                    
                ))}


            </div>
        )   
    }
}

export default users
```

userItem.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'


/// Bring data through from an object into a user card.

 class userItem extends Component {

    render() {

        const { id, login, url } = this.props.users;

        return (
            <div className="card text-center">
                <h2>{login}</h2>
                <a href={url}>View</a>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default userItem
```

Comment: This code should work, notice that your component names should start with capital letter. Please provide a codesandbox with reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. Here is a sandbox to the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-bardeen-k9iov?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Aside from many inconsistent typo mistakes, in your `App.js` you are rendering the `UserItem` without passing any prop, therefore its `undefined`.

After fixing all typos and removing the component as mentioned above, code works as expected: https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-northcutt-w5c3c?file=/src/components/users/UserItem.js:0-268

```
class Users extends Component {
  state = {
    users: [
      {
        name: "Dan"
      },
      {
        name: "Kate"
      },
      {
        name: "Putty"
      }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.users.map((user) => (
          <UserItem key={user.name} user={user} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class UserItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const { name } = this.props.user;

    return (
      <div className="card text-center">
        <a href="#a">{name}</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <User />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```